# Update excel VBA to choose range for renaming tabs in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Current: I have code that updates 4 tab (Sheet6, Sheet7, Sheet8, Sheet10) names based on cell values in range D2:D5. This range is populated with formulas, which can result in blanks and is located on a tab named “Calculations”. Each cell is associated with a specific tab:

D2 -> Sheet6. If cell D2 is blank or 0, then hide tab. If not blank, name Sheet6 with text in cell D2.
D3 -> Sheet7. If cell D3 is blank or 0, then hide tab. If not blank, name Sheet7 with text in cell D3.
D4 -> Sheet8. If cell D4 is blank or 0, then hide tab. If not blank, name Sheet8 with text in cell D4.
D5 -> Sheet10. If cell D5 is blank or 0, then hide tab. If not blank, name Sheet10 with text in cell D5.

```
  Sub RenameShts()
   Dim Ws As Worksheet
   Dim i As Long
   Dim Nme As String

   i = 2
   For Each Ws In Sheets(Array(Sheet6.Name, Sheet7.Name, Sheet8.Name, Sheet10.Name))
      Nme = Sheets("Calculations").Range("D" & i).Value
      If Nme = "" Or Nme = "0" Or Nme = "0 0" Then
         Ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
      Else
         Ws.Name = Nme
      End If
      i = i + 1
   Next Ws
End Sub
```

Desired code: Update current code to look at cell E1 on the “Calculations” tab to determine which range to use for naming the 4 tabs (Sheet6, Sheet7, Sheet8, Sheet10). If cell E1 = False, use range D2:D5 for naming the tabs. If cell E1 = True, use range F2:F5 for naming the tabs. I want the same logic to apply, if any of the cells in the range being used is blank or 0, then hide the tab completely.

Comment: Please read [Why is can someone hep me not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're pretty much there already assuming your code works, unless I'm missing something.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RenameShts()
   Dim Ws As Worksheet
   Dim i As Long
   Dim Nme As String

    Dim columnLetter as string

    If Worksheets("Calculations").range("E1").value2 then columnLetter = "D" else columnLetter = "F"

   i = 2
   For Each Ws In Sheets(Array(Sheet6.Name, Sheet7.Name, Sheet8.Name, Sheet10.Name))
      Nme = Sheets("Calculations").Range(columnLetter & i).Value
      If Nme = "" Or Nme = "0" Or Nme = "0 0" Then
         Ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
      Else
         Ws.Name = Nme
      End If
      i = i + 1
   Next Ws
End Sub
```

Untested, written on mobile.

Comment: Also, it is generally better to explicitly refer to a workbook by name in the code, else the code will refer to whatever workbook is active at the time of execution.